# AVSpeechSynthesizer needs to finish before starting again

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, text-to-speech

If I have a button that makes the AVSpeechSynthesizer say "Hello World" every time I press it, the voice won't start speaking again until it's finished the first text-to-speech string.

How do I the following two options?

1. Make it interrupt the previous speech string and start over, when I tap the button
2. Make it speak over top of the previous one (i.e. multiple voices speaking at once)

Here's What I'm doing now. Using this, the button won't start speaking again, until the previous button press has finished talking:

```
@IBAction func helloButton(sender: AnyObject) {    
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello World")
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)
}
```

Comment: Can you do .2 by creating multiple `AVSpeechSynthesizer`s?

Answer (score 4):

In order to interrupt current speech and start a new one, you have to stop the one that is currently being played. In order to do this, you need to keep a reference to your synthesizer and call `stopSpeakingAtBoundary` when you want to start a new speech. Using `.Immediate` as stop boundary will cause it to immediately stop. Keep in mind, that `stopSpeakingAtBounday` will completly clear your current `AVSpeechSynthesizer` queue.

```
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    func helloButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        synthesizer.stopSpeakingAtBoundary(.Immediate)
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello World")
        synthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)
    }
```

Sadly, I'm not aware of solution to your second issue

Comment: This works great for option 1. Thanks! Hopefully someone will have #2 soon.